# Saving data for different custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I have three different posts types registered:

```
register_post_type( 'foo' , $args );
register_post_type( 'bar' , $args );
register_post_type( 'baz' , $args );
```

When I am creating a new, say, "foo" post, I only want to save the meta box for "foo", what do I do?

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

So, if my post_type were called "foo_post":

```
add_meta_box( 
    $id, 
    $title, 
    $callback, 
    // SPECIFY THE POST TYPE HERE!!!
    "foo_post", 
    $context, 
    $priority, 
    $callback_args );
```

What do I do to save only "foo post" meta box when I am creating / edit a "foo post" page?

Comment: If you specify the post type in your `add_meta_box` then it should only add the meta box for that post type, and if there's no meta box no data will be sent... or have I misunderstood...? :S. In your example 'foo_post' should be just 'foo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since save_post gives you the post_id of the current post, you simply want to check what post_type it is by using get_post_type($post_id)

like:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details')

function save_details($post_id)
{
     $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];

     if ('foo_post' == $post_type)
     {
          // save stuff for foo_post
     }
     elseif ('bar_post' == $post_type)
     {
          // save stuff for bar_post
     }
}
```

and so on...

[get_post_type() codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type)

Comment: You should just grab the post type from the $_REQUEST rather than add another DB call. :)

Comment: But custom meta boxes are only added on a *per-post-type* basis, since the `add_meta_box()` call only accepts *one* post type. (Unless multiple `add_meta_box()` calls are made, to add the same meta box to different post types.) **Also**: you should simply be able to globalize `$post`, and use `$post->post_type` here, which I think is inherently safer than using `$_REQUEST` data.

Comment: @ChipBennett I agree using the global $post object for adding meta boxes and the content within the callbacks. However, the $_REQUEST for save_post action gives you what type of post is being saved. Wouldn't it be more efficient to use the supplied $_POST data that's being saved?  I think there may be two different subjects going on here. :)

Comment: I'm not sure the relative efficiency is more than a trivial difference. Both the `$_POST` data *and* the cached `$post` global are available at this point in the processing. In such a scenario, my preference is to use `$post->post_type`, but it may be nothing more than a matter of preference.

Comment: Just a little note for anyone having problems with this routine bombing-out, you might need to remember to handle the 'revision' posttype by adding something like: `elseif ($post_type == 'revision') {return;}` . Works great though!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about a *custom* post meta box? If so, then you need to ensure that you *specify the `$posttype` when you call [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). e.g.:

```
<?php
add_meta_box( 
    $id, 
    $title, 
    $callback, 
    // SPECIFY THE POST TYPE HERE!!!
    $post_type, 
    $context, 
    $priority, 
    $callback_args );
?>
```

If you're *not* referring to a custom post meta box, then you'll need to provide more information, regarding what post meta box you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I added some more detail to my question. What do I put in my callback, "save_details" so that I am only saving this data for my "foo post" custom post type? Does wordress just know to save for that custom post type only?

Comment: Can you post your *actual* `add_meta_box()` code in your question?